# How to update bash 3.1.x to 3.2.x?

Tags: bash

```
# bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)

# yum install bash
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loading "installonlyn" plugin
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
rpmforge                  100% |=========================| 1.9 kB    00:00     
Reading repository metadata in from local files
primary.xml.gz            100% |=========================| 4.0 MB    00:05     
rpmforge  : ################################################## 11467/11467
Parsing package install arguments
Nothing to do
```

Comment: What version of CentOS are you on? You'll be able to tell with `cat /etc/issue` and `uname -a`

Comment: `Fedora Core release 6` `Linux AMTDAUDIT 2.6.22.14-72.fc6 #1 SMP Wed Nov 21 13:44:07 EST 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on an incredibly old, outdated, and unsupported version of Fedora Core, not CentOS.

[Fedora Core 6 was end-of-lifed on 2007-12-07](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system)#Version_history), and because of Fedora Core's rapid release cycle, it is almost never seen on servers. Consider migrating to a more enterprise-friendly distro with longer support cycles (like CentOS).

If you *must* get a newer version of bash on this system, you'll probably have to compile it from source. But, seriously, migrate to something that's been released this decade.